# Vcash privacy and scaling compared with Monero?

Tags: ringct, privacy, dynamic-blocksize-limit

How do Vcash privacy and scaling functions compare with Monero?

How does the privacy provided by Chainblender, used by Vcash compare with [RingCT](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/95/what-is-ringct-and-how-does-it-compare-to-confidential-transactions) for Monero?

Monero has had [dynamic block sizes](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-there-any-block-size-limitation) since day one. How does that scaling algorithm compare with what was introduced by Vcash in [May of 2016](https://github.com/john-connor/vcash/commit/05bcd3d9a450a53201093dfd45e47e75ab5d5adc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike Monero which has [many developers](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/553/how-many-different-developers-have-made-contributions-to-monero-source-code), Vcash arguably has a bus factor of 1. After recently being doxxed, its developer is alleged to have made [harmful changes](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1504342.msg17125417#msg17125417) to the code before abandoning the project:

> Zero day flaw that allows miners to opt-out of paying incentive rewards to nodes

The operator of the suprnova mining pool had [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1699735.msg17043582#msg17043582) to say:

> I've thought about this, but it would be necessary to fork away from "his" code into a trusted coinbase setup as he simply could have coded too many "backdoors" into his code.. It was him obviously very easy possible to fork off pools and bigger miners from "his" chain and make "his" chain the valid one, even if the "bad pool" had much more power than him, this should never be possible for any coin.. not with > 51% of the power of the net and of course not with less.. I see lots of problems with the current code.

The security of any coin with that level of centralization of development and control is [dangerous](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1699735.msg17043582#msg17043582):

> Obviously he was able to fork off pools/miners from "his" chain without even having more than 51% of the network, if that is not evidence enough.. Well..
>   And no, it wasn't only my pool Smiley
>
> I'm running pools for years and I know very well how to "protect" them, or was anything hacked ? He forked off and banned the node(s) of my pool three times, invalidating blocks on the pool even while the pool had a lot more than 50 % of the network.

Regarding scaling, Monero developer "smooth" [said](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1699735.msg17043582#msg17043582):

> I'll start with this deleted post that was removed by one of their scam promoters claiming that Bitcoin is going "copy Vcash" by adding an adaptive blocksize. I pointed out that Monero (and previously Bytecoin) had such an adaptive blocksize almost a year before Vcash launched.

Well known Bitcoin developer Greg Maxwell posting a warning about Vcash on [Bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=920344.msg10111210#msg10111210) and after the failure of "John Connor" to remedy a clear [copyright violation](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=920344.msg10125574#msg10125574):

> FWIW, I politely reported the copyright violation (the code being a copy of Bitcoin Core run through an auto-formatter with all the attribution removed) as an issue on the github for the project and john-connor accused me of stalking him and then hid the issue tracker on that github from public view. :-/
>
> I suppose I shouldn't be surprised as it's consistent with the rest of the concerns that resulted in creating this thread-- that there is some ongoing effort to keep that work out of the sunlight.

As a result of these warning signed, other developers avoided the project. With a bus factor of one a thorough review of the Vcash privacy system was never completed. It appears to use some sort of a CoinJoin based mixing system similar to [DASH](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/112/how-is-monero-compared-to-dash) meaning it does not offer privacy by a default like Monero. It also means that the privacy provided is far inferior to Monero with ring signatures and stealth addresses today and [RingCT](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/what-is-ringct-and-how-does-it-make-monero-private) in January.

Answer (score 3):

Does any sufficiently detailed specification of ChainBendover even exist?

(this is an answer, not a question)

ChainBlender was afaik never sufficiently documented to even determine whether it could possibly work and so as to be able to determine what the code is supposed to be doing.